# sprintf crashing

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

```
 int main()
 {
     char buf1[100], buf[100]="ddl";

     sprintf(buf1, "log_name = '%.*s'", buf);
  }
```

The above program is crashing. I am not able to understand why is this crashing.
As far as I know before the character makes `printf` to skip the format code and assign buf to next format code.
But here what is the significance of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format specifier `"%.*s"` requires the number of characters to be written to be specified:

```
sprintf(buf1, "log_name = '%.*s'", 3, buf); /* For example */
                                /* ^ */
```

In the posted code only `buf` is provided so there are missing arguments, which is undefined behaviour (in this case a crash).

Note, in this case, `"%s"` would serve just as well as `buf` is null terminated (no requirment for a length *unless* all characters in `buf` must not be copied).

Answer (score 2):

You can see the effect of this as follows .

```
int main()
{   
printf("%.*s",13,"stackoverflow rocks");
}
```

which will give you only `stackoverflow` .

Comment: @ Abhineet :Glad to listen this.Thanks.